# Javascript: Add CSS class and save to cookie

Tags: javascript, css, cookies

*Unfortunately I am a newbie in Javascript and need your help and knowledge, please.*

**CASE:** 
I try to develop a "contrast changer" to make  a Wordpress website more available and cover sight disorderd users as well. 
Now I need to **save the latest CSS class to a cookie** and load it back. 
*In this case the contrast settings would be saved and available, after clicking a link or reload the page and I have no idea how to fix this.*

I am thankful for any ideas and suggestions.

See full snippet on CodePen: https://codepen.io/matt-prime/pen/abzGEoY

```js
// CONTRAST CHANGER
$(document).ready(function(){

 
  // CONTRAST DEFAULT
  $(".change-reset").click(function(){
    $("*").removeClass("contrast-black-white contrast-white-black contrast-yellow-blue contrast-blue-yellow");
  });

  // CONTRAST BLACK WHITE
  $(".changeBW").click(function(){
    $("*").removeClass("contrast-black-white contrast-white-black contrast-yellow-blue contrast-blue-yellow");
    $("*").addClass("contrast-black-white");
  });

  // CONTRAST WHITE BLACK
  $(".changeWB").click(function(){
    $("*").removeClass("contrast-black-white contrast-white-black contrast-yellow-blue contrast-blue-yellow");
    $("*").addClass("contrast-white-black");
    $(".toolbar").removeClass("contrast-white-black");
  });

  // CONTRAST YELLOW BLUE
  $(".changeYB").click(function(){
    $("*").removeClass("contrast-black-white contrast-white-black contrast-yellow-blue contrast-blue-yellow");
    $("*").addClass("contrast-yellow-blue");
    $(".toolbar").removeClass("contrast-yellow-blue");
  });

  // CONTRAST BLUE YELLOW
  $(".changeBY").click(function(){
    $("*").removeClass("contrast-black-white contrast-white-black contrast-yellow-blue contrast-blue-yellow");
    $("*").addClass("contrast-blue-yellow");
    $(".toolbar").removeClass("contrast-blue-yellow");
  });
  
})
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

body {
  margin: 0 !important;
  font-size:16px !important;
  background-color: burlywood !important;
}
/*******************************************************/
/**                Sizes based on:                    **/
/** The Markup Language (an HTML language reference)  **/
/**         W3C Working Group Note 28, May 2013       **/
/**           https://www.w3.org/TR/html/             **/
/*******************************************************/

h1 {
/* TEST */
  padding: 1em 2em;
  border: 0.2em solid;
  text-align: center;
/* TEST END */

  font-size: 2em !important;
  line-height: 2.34em !important;

}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.5em !important;
  margin: 1.2450em !important;
  line-height: 1.74em !important;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1.17em !important;
  margin: 1.1699em !important;
  line-height: 1.41em !important;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 1em !important;
  margin: 1.3300em !important;
  line-height: 1.2em !important;
}

h5 {
  font-size: 0.83em !important;
  margin: 1.3860em !important;
  line-height: 0.92em !important;
}

h6 {
  font-size: 0.67em !important;
  margin: 1.5611em !important;
  line-height: 0.76em !important;
}

p {
  font-size: 1em !important;
  margin: 1em !important;
  line-height: 1.2em !important;
}


 ul {
   font-size: 1em !important;
   margin: 1em !important; 
   line-height: 1.2em !important;
 }

 li {
   font-size: 1em !important;
   margin: 0em !important;
   line-height: 1.2em !important;
 }

 table, td {
   font-size: 1em !important;
   margin: 0em !important;
   line-height: 1.2em !important;
 }

 pre {
   font-size: 0.8125em !important;
   margin: 0.8125em !important;
   line-height: 0.92em !important;
 }

 div,
 section {
   font-size: 1em !important;
   margin: 0em !important; 
   line-height: 1.2em !important;
}

 input,
 button {
   font-size: 0.6879em !important;
   margin: 0.125em !important;
   line-height: 0.8125em !important;
}

.toolbar {
  background:#0B0B61;
  border-bottom:1px solid;
  
/* overflow:hidden; */
/* font-size:1.8em; */

}

a.toolbar:hover,
a.toolbar:focus {background:orange !important;}

.icon {
  padding-right:0.5em;
}

nav {
 margin: 0px auto;
 display: inline-block;
}

.content,
section {
  max-width:1080px;
  padding: 1em;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.left {float:left;}

.dropdown-menu {
 background-color: #0B0B61 !important;
  color: white !important;
 /* border: 1px solid #ccc; */
 border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
 border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px !important;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.175);
 box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.175);
 background-clip: padding-box;
  margin-top: 0px !important;
  padding: 7px 0 !important;
  margin-left: 0 !important;
}

.dropdown-menu > li > a {
 display: block;
 padding: 0.5em 0.9em !important;
 clear: both;
 font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
 /* color: white !important; */
 white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif !important;
  text-transform: none;

}

.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
 text-decoration: none;
}

.btn {
  font-size: 1.2em !important;
}

.btn-label {

}

.btn-default::after {
 content: "⯆";
 display: inline-block;
}

.btn-default {
 color: white !important; 
 background-color: #0B0B61 !important;
 border-color: white !important;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  border:0 !important;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif !important;
}

.btn-default:hover,
.btn-default:focus {
  color: white !important;
  background-color: orange !important;
  border-left: :1px solid #0B0B61 !important;
  border-right: :1px solid #0B0B61 !important;
}

/** CSS CLASSES CONTRAST SUBMENU **/
/* CONTRAST BUTTON DEFAULT */
.contrast-default {color: white !important;}
.contrast-default:hover,
.contrast-default:focus,
.contrast-default:active {
  background-color: orange!important;
  border-color: white!important;
  color:white!important;
  
}

/* CONTRAST BUTTON BLACK WHITE */
.contrast-sw {color: white !important;}
.contrast-sw:hover,
.contrast-sw:focus,
.contrast-sw:active {
  background-color: white!important;
  border-color: black!important;
  color:black!important;
}

/* CONTRAST BUTTON WHITE BLACK */
.contrast-ws {color: white !important;}
.contrast-ws:hover,
.contrast-ws:focus,
.contrast-ws:active {
  background-color: black!important;
  border-color: white!important;
  color:white!important;
}

/* CONTRAST BUTTON YELLOW BLUE */


.contrast-gb {color: white !important;}
.contrast-gb:hover,
.contrast-gb:focus,
.contrast-gb:active {
  background-color: #003AFF!important;
  border-color: #FFFA06!important;
  color:#FFFA06!important;
  /* font-weight: bold; */
}


/* CONTRAST BUTTON BLUE YELLOW */


.contrast-bg {color: white !important;}
.contrast-bg:hover,
.contrast-bg:focus,
.contrast-bg:active {
  background-color: #FFFA06!important;
  border-color: #003AFF!important;
  color:#003AFF!important;
}

/** CSS CLASS CONTRAST SUBMENU BUTTON END **/

/** CSS CLASS CONTRAST LAYOUT **/

/* CONTRAST LAYOUT BLACK WHITE */
.contrast-black-white {
  background-color: white!important;
  border-color: black!important;
  color:black!important;
}

/* CONTRAST LAYOUT WHITE BLACK */
.contrast-white-black {
  background-color: black!important;
  border-color: white!important;
  color:white!important;
  }

/* CONTRAST LAYOUT YELLOW BLUE */
.contrast-yellow-blue {
  background-color: #003AFF!important;
  border-color: #FFFA06!important;
  color:#FFFA06!important;
}

/* CONTRAST LAYOUT BLUE YELLOW */
.contrast-blue-yellow {
  background-color: #FFFA06!important;
  border-color: #003AFF!important;
  color:#003AFF!important;
}
/** CSS CLASS CONTRAST LAYOUT END **/
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Contrast Changer</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-3AB7yXWz4OeoZcPbieVW64vVXEwADiYyAEhwilzWsLw+9FgqpyjjStpPnpBO8o8S" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

  <body>
    <div class="toolbar" role="none">
      <nav role="navigation">
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button title="Contrast"class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <i class="icon fas fa-adjust"></i>
            <span class="btn-label">Contrast</span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            
            <li>
              <a aria-label="Contrast Reset" href="#" class="change-reset contrast-default">Reset</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a aria-label="Contrast Black White" href="#" class="changeBW contrast-sw">Black / White</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a aria-label="Contrast White Black" href="#" class="changeWB contrast-ws">White / Black</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a aria-label="Contrast Yellow Blue" href="#" class="changeYB contrast-gb">Yellow / Blue</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a aria-label="Contrast Blue Yellow" href="#" class="changeBY contrast-bg">Blue / Yellow</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
    
    <div class="a11y">
      <section class="content" role="main">
        <h1>Heading 1</h1>
        <h2>Heading 2</h2>
        <h3>Heading 3</h3>
        <h4>Heading 4</h4>
        <h5>Heading 5</h5>
        <h6>Heading 6</h6>
        <p strong>Paragraph</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </p>
      </section>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `document.cookie` as mentioned [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

working demo on codepen: https://codepen.io/Rockingpg0/pen/GRgddgb

Answer (score 0):

Use these two cookie functions to set and get a cookie. In the setCookie() function I did set an expiration of 90 days (time in msec.), you can change this in the best value for your website.

```
function setCookie(cookieName, cookieValue) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (90 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)); // 90 days
  document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + cookieValue + ";expires=" + d.toUTCString() + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cookieName) {
  var name = cookieName + "=";
  var i, c, ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1);
    if (c.indexOf(name)  == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
  }
  return "";
}

// how to get the cookie
var cValue = getCookie("contrast");
if (cValue == "") {
  // cookie not set yet
} else {
  // cookie in variable cValue
}

// how to set the cookie
setCookie("contrast", "contrast-blue-yellow");
```

Comment: Thank you for investigating my problem, but first answer is very compact and easy to use. That's why I have chosen one.

Comment: If you read the cookie with `document.cookie`, it will return all cookies in one string. Did you work this out? This function will do the job for you.